# dplyr::filter used with a function on string representation of factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some 20 columns and some 10^7 rows.  One of the columns is an id column that is a factor.  I want to filter the rows by properties of the string representation of the levels of the factor.  The code below achieves this, but seems to me to be really rather inelegant.  In particular that I have to create a vector of the relevant ids seems to me should not be needed.

Any suggestions for streamlining this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gdata)

dat <- data.frame(id=factor(c("xxx-nld", "xxx-jap", "yyy-aus", "zzz-ita")))

europ.id <- function(id) {
  ctry.code <- substring(id, nchar(id)-2)
  ctry.code %in% c("nld", "ita")
}

ids <- levels(dat$id)
europ.ids <- subset(ids, europ.campaign(ids))

datx <- dat %>% filter(id %in% europ.ids) %>% drop.levels
```

Comment: Do you mean somthing like this `ids <- c("nld", "ita"); dat %>% filter(grepl(paste(ids, collapse = "|"), id)) %>% droplevels` ? or alternatively `ids <- paste(c("nld", "ita"), collapse = "|"); dat %>% slice(grep(ids, id)) %>% droplevels`

Comment: Or without creating the vector in advance: `dat %>% filter(grepl(paste(c("nld", "ita"), collapse = "|"), id))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus That works perfectly!  In combination with your suggestion and reading the docs to understand why that works and my different attempts didn't, I found the solution `dat %>% filter(europ.id(as.character(id)) %>% droplevels`.  `%in%` and `grepl` also first do an `as.character`.  In my real code I added the `as.character` to `europ.id`.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what stackoverflow etiquette says about a question that gets resolved in comments.

Comment: Please answer the question yourself with a small explanation and then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docendo Discimus gave the right answer in comments.  To explain it first see the error I kept getting in my different attempts

```
> dat %>% filter(europ.id(id))
Error in nchar(id) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector
Calls: %>% ... filter_impl -> .Call -> europ.id -> substring -> nchar
```

Then note that his solution works because grepl applies `as.character` to its argument if needed (from the man: a character vector where matches are sought, or an object which can be coerced by as.character to a character vector).  This implicit application of `as.character` also happens if you use `%in%`.  Since this solution is also perfectly performant, we can do the following

```
dat %>% filter(europ.id(as.character(id)) %>% droplevels
```

Or to make it read a bit nicer update the function to

```
europ.id <- function(id) {
  ids <- as.character(id)
  ctry.code <- substring(ids, nchar(ids)-2)
  ctry.code %in% c("nld", "ita")
}
```

and use

```
dat %>% filter(europ.id(id)) %>% droplevels
```

which reads exactly like what I was looking for.